# Snake Like Game - Automatic Movement in one direction after pressing a button

Tags: javascript, java, function

so I am having troubles with automatic movement 
The code I am using is

```
if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40) {
      snake.y ++;
    }
```

which is moving but only when the key is hold, is there a way to let the object move in one direction automatically after just pressing the button. Sorry, if that's a stupid question, I really am not an experienced coder.

Comment: you've tagged javascript and java... which is it

Comment: this is not enough code to help you. Either way, you will need a loop a executes until the next direction is pressed.

Comment: `if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40) {
     while(true) snake.y ++;
    }` but you might need to do other things for a snake game

Answer (score 2):

You should consider giving the snake object another attribute: velocity! Since you are dealing with two dimensions you can define vx and vy as the two components of the velocity, and when a key is pressed you can change the velocity to the appropriate value, for example:

```
if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key==40) {
    snake.vx = 0;
    snake.vy = 1;
}
```

As well as this, inside the snake object you should define the position by updating the current position. For this you just add the current velocity.

Hopefully this gets you on the path to a working snake game! If not, let me know and I can try to help out more.

Answer (score 0):

I would use flags, and when you press a key set the flag to true for a while loop. When you press a key, go to a move function and have it move the direction of the flag until another key is pressed or you hit a wall.